# C# : Prevent the user from selecting certain items in listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a set of items in my listbox. The items in a listbox are linked to a particular item in another textbox. The users can add and remove the items from the listbox. If any of the item in the listbox is being used anywhere, then the user should not be able to delete it . I can disable these items, but the client doesn't want to disable the itemsI want to prevent the user from selecting certain items.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is in your listBox ? how did you populate your listBox? does it contain just strings ? or are you using a DataSource ?

Comment: XAML or Windows Forms?

Comment: I am using a datasource . I will be able to know which items to diasble before filling the data to the datasource .

Comment: Why are you showing these items in the first place, if the user isn't allowed to select them??

Comment: The items in a listbox are linked to a particular item in another textbox. The users can add and remove the items from the listbox. If any of the item in the listbox is being used anywhere, then the user should not be able to delete it . I can disable these items, but the client doesn't want to disable the items

Answer (score 1):

Really, you shouldn't. A `ListBox` is a UI convention for showing things that you can select, so if you're going to break that convention and show a mix of things that can or can't be selected you're probably doing things wrong.

You're using a datasource, so instead of just sticking that directly into your `ListBox` you want to filter it (by removing the things that can't be selected) into a different collection that can then act as the `ItemsSource`. Then your `ListBox` only contains things that can be selected.

Or, failing that, handle the `SelectedItem` changing and do something to stop it being set to one of the things you want to disallow. But really, don't do it. It will be a horrible and confusing UI experience. Just show the things that are valid.